# Are files and texts readable for the NSA in video streams like remote desktop?

Tags: security, encryption, stream

I was wondering about the following: if I access another Computer over a video stream, (maybe like remote desktop), could the NSA read the websites and texts from that stream, even though only video is transmitted?

thanks!

Comment: Rem Desktop is not transmitting `video`.

Comment: what is it transmitting then? 
And can you read text from a video that is encrypted?

Comment: If it is properly encrypted, then no. Microsoft's Remote Desktop ought to be that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remote Desktop, as in [RDP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Desktop_Protocol#Features) does not stream video. Unlike other remote desktop software, RDP actually uses kernel level access which is why RDP is so much smoother than a lot of the software that uses images.

RDP is vulnerable to [man-in-the-middle](http://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/detail?vulnId=CVE-2005-1794) attacks, but this is pretty unlikely to happen to you unless you are a highly valuable target. You can use SSL to prevent this sort of thing.

Regardless of all of that, your question seems to be about image-based remote desktop. You are, I think, correct in your assumption that the images are difficult to read vs. just intercepting plain text/html/etc. If the transmission was intercepted, they could "play it back" if it was not encrypted, and see what happened. The thing is, even the transmission between you and the remote host are secure - what about the transmission between the host and the internet? It is likely that whatever you are doing can be traced to the host, and then to you.

Comment: thanks so far. 

So imagine this. I have an autonomous network somewhere.In that autonomous network I have a computer that accesses other computers within said autonomous network.  The only thing is that the video (actual video) of this computer is streamed to another computer outside the autonomous network via the common Internet. Could the (encrypted) video stream be broken down to the files/text that I see, but which look like video to outsiders?

Comment: It would be incredibly difficult to automate such a behavior, and if the encryption you are using is *good*, then it can't be decrypted in any realistic time frame. So, it would require a couple billion hours of computing time (even split among many computers, this is expensive). If somehow the encryption was broken, and the plain video could be seen, then of course, any **person** viewing the video could see what was going on. Since, presumably, you can see what is going on. Just know that if that first autonomous network is subpoenaed, then it is very likely that it could be traced back.